# I am not able to access the attributes of super class

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I was trying to understand inheritance and how constructors work. According to the book I am following, the constructor of the base class is automatically available to sub class but I am still receiving errors.

```
class teacher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.std=10
class student(teacher):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
s=student()
print(s.std)
```

Below lies the error I receive on running the program.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [41], line 8
      6         pass
      7 s=student()
----> 8 print(s.std)

AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'std'
```

Comment: Because you explicitly overrode the initialiser, with an implementation that didn't set it.

Answer (score 0):

using the super().**init**() u can use the initializing function from teacher onto student so student has the init function of teacher(im not sure if u understood this im not really good at teaching)

ur code should look smth like this

```
class teacher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.std=10
class student(teacher):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
s=student()
print(s.std)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation. I think your explanation was really good and straightforward; I was able to understand where I went wrong.